# How to Join list of videofiles(same formatted) into a singleVideofile in android

Tags: android, video, android-mediarecorder

It seems we have no Pause option while recording the video in android.
So the possible way for me is to append the current recorded file to the previous one,
Friends, can any one let me know how to join or merging or concatenate the video files in android.

Thanks in advance...for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mp4parser library https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/
 Here is an [example](https://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/AppendExample.java)